# p:selectOneMenu changed when tab is changed

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a [Primefaces dialog](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogHome.jsf), and inside it there is a [tabView](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewHome.jsf). In this tabView I have 3 tabs, each one called towards ui:include. In the first tab I have a [selectOneMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf) which defines a property called `tipoProprietario` from class `ProprietarioORM`. The navigation between tab is done not by tabs themselves (in this stage they're disabled) but towards commandButtons at bottom of dialog. When I click in a commandButton to pass from the first to second tab `tipoProprietario` is filled correctly. However, when I click to pass from second do third tab (or even to the first one), I found that the selectItem value is changed to `null`. Consequently, the `tipoProprietario` property is also changed to `null`. Debugging, I saw that first it is called the Select Item listener method and after the `tipoProprietario` setter.

Can someone explain why this it is happening? How to correct it?

dialog.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:dialog id="dlgEdicao" widgetVar="dlgEdicao" resizable="false"
        closable="true" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true"
        header="#{(proprietarioMB.edicao)? msg['proprietario.titulo.editar']: msg['proprietario.titulo.incluir']}">
        <p:tabView id="tabEdicao" widgetVar="tabEdicao" dynamic="true"
            styleClass="tabEdicaoProprietario" cache="false"
            binding="#{proprietarioMB.tabEdicao}">
            <p:tab id="tabProprietario" title="#{msg['proprietario.titulo']}"
                disabled="#{not proprietarioMB.edicao}" titleStyleClass="">
                <ui:include src="./aba_proprietario.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab id="tabEnderecoContato"
                title="#{msg['proprietario.titulo.aba.endereco']}"
                disabled="#{not proprietarioMB.edicao}">
                <ui:include src="./aba_endereco_contato.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab id="tabVeiculo"
                title="#{msg['proprietario.titulo.aba.veiculo']}"
                disabled="#{not proprietarioMB.edicao}">
                <ui:include src="./aba_veiculo.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="btnDialogoAnterior"
                value="#{msg['titulo.anterior']}"
                rendered="#{not proprietarioMB.edicao}" immediate="true"
                disabled="#{not proprietarioMB.btnAnteriorHabilitado}"
                actionListener="#{proprietarioMB.doEventClickBtnAnterior}"
                update="@this tabEdicao btnDialogoSeguinte btnDialogoConcluir"
                style="margin-right: 20px;" />

            <p:commandButton id="btnDialogoSeguinte"
                value="#{msg['titulo.proximo']} #{(not proprietarioMB.btnConcluirVisivel)? '': 'display: none;'}"
                rendered="#{not proprietarioMB.edicao}"
                actionListener="#{proprietarioMB.doEventClickBtnSeguinte}"
                update="@this tabEdicao btnDialogoAnterior btnDialogoConcluir"
                style="margin-right: 20px; #{(not proprietarioMB.btnConcluirVisivel)? '': 'display: none;'}" />

        </f:facet>

    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

aba_proprietario.xhtml (the first tab)

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:panel id="pnlDadosProprietario">
        <p:focus for="selTipoEdicao" />
        <p:fieldset id="fieldDadosProprietario"
            legend="#{msg['proprietario.titulo']}"
            rendered="#{not empty proprietarioMB.proprietario}">
            <p:panelGrid id="pnlDadosProprietarioEdicao">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel id="lblTipoEdicao"
                            value="#{msg['proprietario.titulo.tipo']}" for="selTipoEdicao" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="selTipoEdicao"
                            value="#{proprietarioMB.proprietario.tipoProprietario}"
                            valueChangeListener="#{proprietarioMB.doEventTipoDocumentoPesquisaChanged}"
                            immediate="true">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{proprietarioMB.tiposProprietarios}" />
                            <p:ajax event="change" update="txtDocumentoEdicao" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel id="lblDocumentoEdicao"
                            value="#{msg['proprietario.titulo.documento']}"
                            for="txtDocumentoEdicao" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputMask id="txtDocumentoEdicao"
                            value="#{proprietarioMB.proprietario.documento}"
                            mask="#{proprietarioMB.mascaraDocumento}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:fieldset>
    </p:panel>
</ui:composition>
```

The Managed Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProprietarioMB {


    private static final String MASCARA_CPF = "999.999.999-99";

    private static final String MASCARA_CNPJ = "99.999.999/9999-99";

    private static final SelectItem[] tiposProprietarios = new SelectItem[] {
            new SelectItem(JURIDICA, JURIDICA.getDescricao()),
            new SelectItem(FISICA, FISICA.getDescricao()), };

    private ProprietarioORM proprietario;

    private String mascaraDocumento;

    private TabView tabEdicao;

    /**
     * Select Item listener method: Changes inputMask mask
     */
    public void doEventTipoDocumentoPesquisaChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            this.mascaraDocumento = (event.getNewValue() == FISICA) ? MASCARA_CPF
                    : MASCARA_CNPJ;
    }

    public void doEventClickBtnAnterior() {
        System.out.println("ProprietarioMB.doEventClickBtnAnterior(): "
                + this.tabEdicao.getActiveIndex());
            this.tabEdicao.setActiveIndex(this.tabEdicao.getActiveIndex() - 1);
    }

    public void doEventClickBtnSeguinte() {
        System.out.println("ProprietarioMB.doEventClickBtnSeguinte(): "
                + this.tabEdicao.getActiveIndex());
        System.out.println("ProprietarioMB.doEventClickBtnSeguinte(): "
                + this.proprietario);
        if (this.tabEdicao.getActiveIndex() == 0) {
            if (this.validarProprietario()) { // Validation method
                this.tabEdicao.setActiveIndex(1);
            }
        } else if (this.tabEdicao.getActiveIndex() == 1) {
            this.tabEdicao.setActiveIndex(2);
        }
    }

    // Other methods + getters & setters

}
```

ProprietarioORM

```
public class ProprietarioORM {

    private String nome;

    private TipoProprietarioEnum tipoProprietario;

    // getters & setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because of the `binding="#{proprietarioMB.tabEdicao}"`

For one thing, you don't appear to need the binding at all. Even if you did, you failed to initialize the component in your backing bean, a bug that'll result in the `<p:tabView/>` attempting to bind to a null variable `tabEdicao`.

As you don't appear to be using the tabview variable in the backing bean, my recommendation would be to get rid of it. If you really need it, just initialize it:

```
private TabView tabEdicao = new TabView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Kolossus:

This issue was resolved when I added the attibute `dynamic="true"` to dialog. Actually, the real value was `dynamic=#{empty proprietarioMB.proprietario}`, because I was geting `NullPointerException` when loading the page. `proprietario` property is loaded towards `@PostConstruct` method.